# SQL select statement to view items in two tables stored by JPA

Tags: java, mysql, database, jpa, orm

I have a Playlist that stores track id's in it from an XML file. I would like to be able to view all information about a song in a playlist by a select statement.

A lot of the select statements I have tried have been unsuccessful so I'm not sure I'm going about it the right way.

My entities in the JPA are like this:

```
@NamedQueries( {
@NamedQuery(name = "Playlist.findAll", query = "select o from Playlist o"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Playlist.findByName", query = "select o from Playlist o where o.name=:name"),
})

@Entity
public class Playlist {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

private String name, persistentId, libraryPersistentId;
private double playlistId;

@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private List<Song> tracks;

public Playlist(String name, String persistentId, double playlistId, List<Song> tracks, String libraryPersistentId) {
    this.name = name;
    this.persistentId = persistentId;
    this.playlistId = playlistId;
    this.tracks = tracks;
    this.libraryPersistentId = libraryPersistentId;
}

public Playlist() {
}



@NamedQueries( {
@NamedQuery(name = "Song.findAll", query = "select o from Song o"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Song.findByName", query = "select o from Song o where o.name=:name"),
})

@Entity
public class Song {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

private double songid, year;
private String name, artist, album, genre, persistentId, libraryPersistentId;


public Song(double songid, String name, String artist,
        String album, String genre, double year, String persistentId, String libraryPersistentId) {
    this.songid = songid;
    this.name = name;
    this.artist = artist;
    this.album = album;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.year = year;
    this.persistentId = persistentId;
    this.libraryPersistentId = libraryPersistentId;
}

public Song() {

}
```

And this is how my tables look like in mysql:

[image: Database]

I was thinking something like SELECT * FROM Song WHERE playlist_id = playlist_song.playlist_id but that didn't work. Could anyone help?

Comment: "have been unsuccessful". Care to share what "unsuccessful" means? or do we have to guess?

Comment: @NeilStockton Sorry, should have went into more detail. I got an error saying something like "playlist_song.playlist_id can not be found".

Comment: so you put that SQL into "createQuery(...)" which takes in JPQL ?

Comment: This was just in the mysql cmd client but I will be using it in a jsp file when I get it working.

Answer (score 0):

When you type query=". Then press Ctrl + spacebar to see if it automatically generates the templates of sql statements .

Comment: you referring to some IDE ? because the OP says nothing about what environment they are using. Reading his mind?